# Apply Theme in silverlight to entire application

Tags: c#, silverlight, componentone

I am trying to apply a ComponentOne theme to my silverlight application; however, I am having trouble getting it to work. Anyone know what I am missing?

I am trying to add it under App.xaml.cs for application_startup:

```
Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new C1ThemeWhistlerBlue());
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out another way to do it. Add the following line to the Application_startup in app.xaml.cs:

```
new C1ThemeWhistlerBlue().Apply((FrameworkElement)Current.RootVisual);
```

This will add the theme Whistler Blue.

To remove the theme you need to clear the Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries (or just remove that object from it).